# How to remove a TF from a ROS bag?

Tags: rosbag, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a bag that contains a large TF tree where one TF (base_link->virtual_cam) was calculated based on several TFs and parameters. I would like to replay this bag without this generated TF in order to interactively re-generate it as a play the bag.

Hence the question, how do I remove this TF from the bag? Alternatively, can I play the bag without outputting this TF?

Specs: Ubuntu 12.04, Fuerte

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/56935/how-to-remove-a-tf-from-a-ros-bag?/) by [Benoit Larochelle](https://answers.ros.org/users/216/benoit-larochelle/) on ROS Answers with karma: 867 on 2013-03-03

Post score: 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use the [rosbag filter](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosbag/Commandline#filter) command to generate a new bag file filtering out the topics you do not want.
For example, I used this command

```
rosbag filter input.bag output.bag 'topic == "/camera/image_raw/compressed" or topic == "/scan" or topic == "/timetag" or  topic == "/tf" and m.transforms[0].header.frame_id != "/odom" and m.transforms[0].child_frame_id != "/odom"'
```

here I want to keep the topics **/camera/image_raw/compressed** , **/scan** and **/timetag** and also the **/tf** EXCEPT the ones that had **/odom** either as a frame_id or as a child_frame_id, effectively removing only some **/tf** messages instead of all of them.

in your case you can use adapt the above example to fit your needs:

```
rosbag filter input.bag output.bag 'topic == "ALL THE TOPICS YOU WANT TO KEEP" or topic == "/tf" and m.transforms[0].header.frame_id != "/base_link" and m.transforms[0].child_frame_id != "/virtual_cam"'
```

---

EDIT: as pointed by @Ben_S, this is a more concise form, with the same results (from [this answer](https://answers.ros.org/question/12285/gmapping-simulation/?answer=18124#post-id-18124)):

```
rosbag filter input.bag output.bag 'topic != "/tf" or topic == "/tf" and m.transforms[0].header.frame_id != "/base_link" and m.transforms[0].child_frame_id != "/virtual_cam"'
```

---

Originally posted by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) with karma: 4402 on 2013-03-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 32

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Benoit Larochelle](https://answers.ros.org/users/216/benoit-larochelle/) on 2013-03-03**:
This tool seems really useful (it could have its own page with many examples), but I don't see how to remove a particular TF. All TFs were published to /tf.

**Comment by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) on 2013-03-03**:
check my first example code, there you have to play with the last two conditions to fit your case, meaning you remove tf messages where your frame_id is base_link and the child_frame_id is virtual_cam.

**Comment by [Benoit Larochelle](https://answers.ros.org/users/216/benoit-larochelle/) on 2013-03-04**:
I think that this alone should work, but I did not try it: rosbag filter input.bag output.bag 'm.transforms[0].child_frame_id != "/virtual_cam"'. I'm working with a recording of 30+ GB in several bags, so the other solution was more practical. I would mark this as correct if I could choose two. :-)

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-03-04**:
You'll need the more complex commands given in the answer as the condition will be evaluated for every message, not only tf. So accessing `m.transforms` will give you an assertion.

**Comment by [hitzg](https://answers.ros.org/users/10606/hitzg/) on 2014-01-08**:
This will only work if you are sure that only one transformation is sent in every message (i.e. there is only one element in m.transforms).

**Comment by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) on 2014-01-09**:
I know that what it looks like, due to the [0] index, but actually I tested it with many transformations in each message and it works. Have you tried it?

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2015-05-14**:
This should work for up to five transforms being broadcast in a single message, and it can be extended:

https://gist.github.com/ayrton04/662964298a82211a7e28

**Comment by [littlelordy2](https://answers.ros.org/users/39747/littlelordy2/) on 2019-01-30**:
@Procópio there's a typo in the edited solution. It's 'topic != "tf" or ...' but it should be 'topic != "**/**tf" or ...'

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I dont know of any solution to completely remove only one TF from a bag, but if the transform you want to remove is to a leaf of the tree, you could try remapping it to an unused frame.

Have a look at [tf_remap](http://www.ros.org/wiki/tf#Nodes) and the description of the node. You could leave all frames unchanged except for the one you want to have removed. But i think this will only work for leafs of the tree. (Or you would have to remap the whole branch of the tree and redefine it while playing back the bag)

---

Originally posted by [Ben_S](https://answers.ros.org/users/1072/ben_s/) with karma: 2510 on 2013-03-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) on 2013-03-04**:
you can remove only one specific tf creating a condition in the rosbag filter (check my code example). there I kept all the tf except the ones that had /odom either as the frame_id or the child_frame_id. of course your remap alternative also should do the job.

**Comment by [Ben_S](https://answers.ros.org/users/1072/ben_s/) on 2013-03-04**:
Yes, you wrote your comment just while i was typing this answer. In the meantime i also found this answer http://answers.ros.org/question/12285/gmapping-simulation/?answer=18124#post-id-18124 where brian gave the same solution. :) A use case that i also stumbled across some weeks ago.

**Comment by [Benoit Larochelle](https://answers.ros.org/users/216/benoit-larochelle/) on 2013-03-04**:
I tried rosrun tf tf_remap _mappings:='[{old: /ptz, new: /ptz_original}]' and rosrun tf tf_remap _mappings:='[{old: /map/odom/base_link/omnicam/ptz, new: /map/odom/base_link/omnicam/ptz_original}]' but both have no effect. I get no errors, but I get only the old frames, not the new ones.

**Comment by [Ben_S](https://answers.ros.org/users/1072/ben_s/) on 2013-03-04**:
Using your first commandline works for me:
`rosrun tf tf_remap _mappings:='[{old: /imu_link, new: /imu_link_old}]'`
Applying the following mappings to incoming tf frame ids {'/imu_link': '/imu_link_old'}
Remember to play the bag with `rosbag play x.bag /tf:=/tf_old`

**Comment by [Benoit Larochelle](https://answers.ros.org/users/216/benoit-larochelle/) on 2013-03-04**:
Yes, you're right! I had not read the part about remapping the tf topic, and was I wondering what kind of black magic would make this work. Now it makes sense. Also to confirm, I have to use the short TF names and not the fully qualified names.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You could try a script we did to do exactly the same. It is located in our public repo [srv_tools](https://github.com/srv/srv_tools), which is not fully documented yet on [ROS](http://www.ros.org/wiki/srv_tools). The script you look for is [this one](https://github.com/srv/srv_tools/blob/groovy/bag_tools/scripts/remove_tf.py).

---

Originally posted by [Miquel Massot](https://answers.ros.org/users/2515/miquel-massot/) with karma: 1471 on 2013-03-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Benoit Larochelle](https://answers.ros.org/users/216/benoit-larochelle/) on 2013-03-05**:
Thanks, the script is short and simple! Just the way I like it! ;-)

**Comment by [hitzg](https://answers.ros.org/users/10606/hitzg/) on 2014-01-08**:
Works like a charm! The direct link does not work anymore, here's one to the file on github:
remove_tf

**Comment by [benabruzzo](https://answers.ros.org/users/2641/benabruzzo/) on 2015-03-19**:
404 on the link for "this one" : remove_tf.py

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2015-03-19**:
A quick search finds what I think is the content here: http://docs.ros.org/hydro/api/bag_tools/html/remove__tf_8py_source.html